# delete duplicate with a specific criteria

Tags: duplicates, criteria, sql-delete

I have a table and remove all duplicates according to "serviceWoNumber"   but code should decide which duplicates shoould remain by considering "type"

**First table:**

```
serialNo           serviceWoNumber         type   

900017672280000         1700028713           CD 

731127155164500         1600712441           FD    

731127155164500         1600712441           CD

900017672280000         1700028713           CD  

900017672280000         1700028713           CD 

359864066017456          325088621           FD  

359864066017456          325088621           CD
```

**Table I need:**

```
serialNo           serviceWoNumber         type   

900017672280000         1700028713           CD 

731127155164500         1600712441           FD  

359864066017456          325088621           FD
```

I would be very appreciated for any help
Thank you

Comment: @EluciusFTW thank you

I tried


>DELETE CD_FD.[SerWorkNumber], CD_FD.[SerialNo], CD_FD.[ServiceCenter], CD_FD.[ReceivedDate], CD_FD.[Type]
FROM CD_FD
WHERE (((CD_FD.[SerWorkNumber]) In (SELECT [SerWorkNumber] FROM [CD_FD] As Tmp GROUP BY [SerWorkNumber] HAVING Count(*)>1 )) AND ((CD_FD.[Type])="CD"));

but it removes all "CD" type

Comment: @EluciusFTW do you have any solution for it?

Thank you very much